# Problem Init DLC Model in deeplabcut-live gui

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tkinter, deeplab

after exporting my model that i've trained in google colab, I initialize the camera it comes up Ok. I have no Processor for now.
I select the model and click "Init DLC" and I get the error in the image below (when the camera is ON). Did I do something wrong?

[when the camera is on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1hTu.jpg)

```py
/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Process SpawnProcess-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 426, in import_graph_def
    graph._c_graph, serialized, options)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef mentions attr 'explicit_paddings' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]; attr=dilations:list(int),default=[1, 1, 1, 1]>; NodeDef: {{node DLC/resnet_v1_50/conv1/Conv2D}}. (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dlclivegui/pose_process.py", line 73, in _run_pose
    ret = self._open_dlc_live(dlc_params)
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dlclivegui/pose_process.py", line 96, in _open_dlc_live
    self.frame, frame_time=self.frame_time[0], record=False
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dlclive/dlclive.py", line 275, in init_inference
    graph = finalize_graph(graph_def)
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dlclive/graph.py", line 58, in finalize_graph
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="DLC")
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 430, in import_graph_def
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: NodeDef mentions attr 'explicit_paddings' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]; attr=dilations:list(int),default=[1, 1, 1, 1]>; NodeDef: {{node DLC/resnet_v1_50/conv1/Conv2D}}. (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
```

and this is the error i get when the camera is OFF

[when the Camera is Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFFDp.png)

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 749, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/home/david/anaconda3/envs/dlc-live/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dlclivegui/dlclivegui.py", line 849, in start_pose
    ret = self.cam_pose_proc.start_pose_process(dlc_params)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start_pose_process'
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with `tkinter`. Also please provide a working minimal example of your code.

Comment: acttualy the problem was from the tensorflow and I have fixed if by running this command

export TF_XLA_FLAGS= --tf_xla_cpu_global_jit